# OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec:

Tags: image, docker, containers, exec

I have created image with our application, after running the image i can see the docker containers are also created, when I am trying to getinto the docker container i am getting the below error, can you please help me here.

> """"OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown""""

I have tried to execute all the below commands

```
 docker run -it exec 962f5d99458c
 docker run -it 962f5d99458c
 docker exec -it 962f5d99458c /bin
 docker exec -it 75f6cb44f9e1
 docker run --rm -ti 962f5d99458c sh
 docker run --rm -ti 962f5d99458c /bin
 docker exec  --rm -ti 962f5d99458c /bin
 docker exec  -ti 962f5d99458c /bin
 docker exec  -ti 962f5d99458c \bin
 docker exec -it 75f6cb44f9e1 bash
```

but no luck..... can you please help me here.

Comment: Looks like `bash` is not available in your container. Did you try `sh`?
`docker exec -it <container-id> sh`

What is the base image?

Comment: Please include a [mcve], including an example Dockerfile and any dependencies, to recreate your issue.

Answer (score 10):

What the error says is that the startup command is invalid because the image has no (or it's not on `$PATH`) certain executable in it (`bash` in this case). The absence of `bash` is adequate for certain images (e.g. based on Alpine Linux or `scratch`) but if there is any shell at all, you can use `sh`:

```sh
# create a container from image and get straight into shell
docker run -it <image> sh

# or start a container in background, then get into shell
docker run -d <image>
docker exec -it <container> sh
```

If the image has no shell in it, then the only way to launch it, is by using the binary of the application the image supposed to run. Normally it works out of the box, unless you've overridden `ENTRYPOINT` and/or `CMD` in Dockerfile or by `run` arguments. The default startup arguments can be found with `docker inspect`:

```sh
docker image inspect nginx | jq '.[0].Config.Entrypoint'
docker image inspect nginx | jq '.[0].Config.Cmd'
```

In case you absolutely sure that the executable is there but still get the error, using an absolute path might help (e.g. `/bin/bash` instead of simply `bash`).

Comment: I have created my script to run the following services.

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                  NAMES
962f5d99458c        nginx:1.17.4-alpine   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   54 minutes ago      Up 54 minutes                  0.0.0.0:8854->80/tcp   webserver
75f6cb44f9e1        drupal_drupal         "docker-php-entrypoi…"   54 minutes ago      Up 54 minutes                  9000/tcp               drupal
6efa48cb12eb        postgres:11           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   55 minutes ago  Restart

Comment: For nginx you can use `ash` or `sh`: `docker exec -it 962f5d99458c ash`. For postgres even `bash` should work. As for Drupal, I need to see Dockerfile to tell for sure, but I guess `sh` will do. You can add both the Dockerfile and this output to your question.

Comment: sh works for nginx:alpine